# how to extrct particular string from string and increment that in c# using regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

i have created one id - i want to increment that id . for that i need to replace the string in a string

input string - KST-HYD/15-116/001/CST

i extracted 001, but im unable to replace 001 with 002

code behind

```
 Regex regex = new Regex(@"\/(\d+)\/");
Match match = regex.Match(txtId.Text.Trim());
if (match.Success)
{
    //Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    int oldid = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[1].Value);
    int newid = oldid + 1;
    string newidstring = newid.ToString();
    string idformat = "KST-HYD/15-116/@/CST";
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(idformat);
    builder.Replace("@",newidstring);
    string newGeneratedId = builder.ToString();
    Response.Write(newGeneratedId);

}
```

Comment: can you tell us more about `001`? is it always fix length of 3 characters? is the rest of the string always fix?

Comment: yes fix length but CST part will change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a one liner solution

```
string txtId = "KST-HYD/15-116/001/CST";            
string result = Regex.Replace(txtId, @"(?<=\/)\d{3}(?=\/)", s => (int.Parse(s.Value)+1).ToString("d3"));
```

UPDATE: RegEx:

`(?<=\/)` number starts with `/` but it's not a part of the number

`\d{3}` the number has always a fix length of 3

`(?=\/)` number ends with `/` but it's not a part of the number

Answer (score 2):

Use `string.Remove`, `string.Insert`, and `Convert.ToInt32`:

```
string txt = match.Groups[1].Value;
int pos = match.Index; //please add this for getting the position for the match
txtId.Text = txtId.Text.Remove(pos + 1, txt.Length).Insert(pos + 1, (Convert.ToInt32(txt) + 1).ToString("d3"));
```

Edit: Thanks for correction from Mr. Giorgi and others. I updated the answer to position-based.

Comment: You will be in trouble if `KST-HYD/15-001/001/CST`

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri But in such case the Regex wouldn't match because the number must be in the form of /Num/.

Comment: @Ian, yes it will match, but you will replace in 2 places.

Comment: @krishnamohan, you will have a problem when you will increment 16 times, then both substring will be replaced on each further iteration!

Comment: i dnt know where i will get the wrong id. for my case its working fine

Comment: this will fail in case `KST-HYD/15-116/116/CST`

Comment: yes yes i got wrong result...KST-HYD/15-117/117/CST   which wrong id

Comment: Hi Krishna, I updated my answer. If "CST" is constant, you can take advantage of it.

Comment: In your edited solution you are relaying on the content of the string while you could just replace at the position of match. That is not good solution.

Comment: cst is not constant it will also change,,according to company names..first 3 letters os each word

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do this to replace exactly at the position where match is found:

```
var t = "KST-HYD/15-116/001/CST";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\/(?<m>\d+)\/");
Match match = regex.Match(t);

if (match.Success)
{
    string txt = match.Groups["m"].Value;
    var pos = match.Index;
    var vali = int.Parse(txt);

    var sb = new StringBuilder(t);
    sb.Remove(pos + 1, txt.Length);
    sb.Insert(pos + 1, (++vali).ToString("000"));

    t = sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: `(?<m>` this is just a naming group and it will extract `001` and not `/001/`. Then you grab the position where match was found and replace at that position with incrementing value.

Comment: @krishnamohan, `t` is `txtId.Text`

Comment: @krishnamohan, I think you should accept fubo's answer.